DDEV fails to start after update (Failed waiting for web/db containers to become ready)
After updating DDEV from 1.21.x to 1.23.4, I cannot start my local environment anymore. After launching ddev start, I get all the containers starting and I see the following in my console:
Starting Mutagen sync process... 
................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................................Mutagen sync flush completed in 13m29s.
For details on sync status 'ddev mutagen st d9 -l' 
Waiting for containers to become ready: [web db] 
Failed waiting for web/db containers to become ready: web container failed: log=/var/www/html:OK mailpit:FAILED phpstatus:FAILED, err=ddev-d9-web container is unhealthy, log=/var/www/html:OK mailpit:FAILED phpstatus:FAILED
Troubleshoot this with these commands: 
[
     ddev logs -s web
     docker logs ddev-d9-web
     docker inspect --format "{{ json .State.Health }}" ddev-d9-web | docker run -i --rm ddev/ddev-utilities jq -r
]

However, there is a temporary solution, that works only once. After I run dev config --database=mariadb:10.4 (my current MariaDB version in the config.yml file) the local environment starts as if nothing happened, but after stopping it, the following start will be with an error again.
Anybody got the same problem? Btw, tried on two different locals, which are completely different, same behaviour.

"Troubleshoot this with these commands" - the commands below will give you more details about the error. But this is hard to debug on StackOverflow, please go to Discord and create a new post in the support channel https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/support/

Also see the troubleshooting guide at https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/stable/users/usage/troubleshooting/ - and in this case it's going to be very important that you remove custom configuration to figure out what's wrong. The most important things to remove will be webimage_extra_packages in .ddev/config.yaml and any .ddev/web-build/Dockerfile*.  The ddev-webserver now is based on a newer version of Debian, so may give you trouble in those places. We welcome you to Discord for support as @stasadev says.

Thanks for your reply, guys! I will be happy to discuss that problem in Discord when I have a bit more time, but the quick fix with disabling mutagen worked for now.

Disabling mutagen resolved my issue (but, probably, not the root of the problem):
ddev mutagen reset && ddev config global --performance-mode=none && ddev config --performance-mode=none


If I recall, the real problem was that you needed to set upload_dirs properly, isn't that correct?
